# Can't access retrieve username and password through req.headers.authorization in SwaggerUi

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, swagger-ui, bearer-token

I am writing the backend using nodejs and express. I have set up the swagger for api documentation. I use the bearer authentication method with the token and it's working in the swagger when put my token through the authorize button. I take my token through my frontend. Basically i run my frontend web app (written in react) and i login using my username and password. Then i take my credentials through the req.headers.authorization and make my token in the backend. What i want is to be able to login through the post request in the swagger ui and not having to open my frontend to do this every time.

````
const options = {
  definition: {
    // Swagger/OpenAPI version
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    // Information about our API
    info: {
      title: "Ai Platform api doc",
      version: "1.0.0",
      description:
        "This is our api documentation for our web application, Ai Platform. Made with express and documented with Swagger",
    },
    // Server configuration
    servers: [
      {
        url: `http://localhost:${port}`,
      },
    ],
    // Security schemes definition
    components: {
      securitySchemes: {
        // Bearer token authentication scheme
        bearerAuth: {
          type: "http",
          scheme: "bearer",
          bearerFormat: "JWT",
          in: "header",
        },
      },
    },
    // Security configuration to apply globally
    security: [
      {
        // Using the defined Bearer token authentication scheme
        bearerAuth: {},
      },
    ],
  },
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};```
````